# Unable to add QuickTime control to Windows Forms project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, activex, quicktime

I'm trying to follow the instructions on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50056/Read-M4A-tags-in-C to host the QuickTime control in a Windows Forms project. I'm using VS2010 with C#.

I've added all the available Apple QuickTime COM references to my project but I don't see the QuickTime control listed in the Toolbox.

In several examples online, people are using `AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl qtPlayerObj = new AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl();` to initialize the control. In my project, I only have `QTOControlLib`, not `AxQTOControlLib`.

I've done this a bunch of times with other controls. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click on your ToolBox select **Choose Items** then select the **Com Components** Tab. You then will want to look for `Apple QuickTime Control 2.0` and select it. When you Click Ok you will then have the Control in your ToolBox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Open a console and browse to the location of `QTOControlLib`. Run `AxImp.exe` with `QTOControlLib.dll` as an argument. It should generate the `AxInterop` which you would then reference in your project.

PS: If you have already added `QTOControlLib.dll` to the toolbox, add a temporary windows form and drag the control on to the form. Visual studio should automatically generate the `AxInterop`. If this does not work try the above mentioned solution.